# Problem to start application with xinit passing to it some parameters

Tags: raspberry-pi, sdl, x11, xorg

I need to launch SDL application from command line with xinit on a Raspberry Pi that doesn't have a Desktop Environment. My application needs some parameters like this:

```
/path_to_my_app/myapp -parameter1 -parameter2 value_for_parameter_2
```

I tried this:

```
xinit -geometry 1920x1080+0+0 /path_to_my_app/myapp -parameter1 -parameter2 value_for_parameter_2
```

but it thinks that `-parameter1` is an argument for **xinit**.

Also on stackoverflow I don't find any working solution, any idea?

Comment: you can write the complete command line for your application into ~/.xinitrc and launch xinit with no arguments at all.

Comment: Created and added `/path_to_my_app/myapp -parameter1 -parameter2 value_for_parameter_2` to ~/.xinitrc, then started with `xinit`. I can't get keyboard and mouse events, do you know why?

Answer (score -2):

did you try

```
xinit -geometry 1920x1080+0+0 /path_to_my_app/myapp - - -parameter1 -parameter2 value_for_parameter_2
```